# Running count-matches across several files

Tags: emacs

Is there a way to use `count-matches` across files?

e.g. I would like to be able to return the no. of instances of a string `"foo"` across all the files in my src dir

Or potentially run count-matches against all the files I have marked in a `dired` buffer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple interactive function implementation.

It works by iterating over all the files returned by `directory-files` and using `count-matches` on their file contents without actually opening up the files.

Called interactively, it will prompt for a directory, a file regexp and a match REGEXP.

For example this would count all occurrences of malloc in .c files inside your src dir.

```lisp
(count-matches-in "./src/" "\\.c$" "\\<malloc\\>")
```

```lisp
(defun count-matches-in (dir file-match match)
  "Count all occurrences of regexp MATCH in files whose name matches FILE-MATCH inside DIR.

When called interactively, display the count in the echo area."
  (interactive "DDir: \nsFiles Matching: \nsRegexp: ")
  (with-temp-buffer
    (let ((count (apply '+ (mapcar (lambda (f)
                     (delete-region (point-min) (point-max))
                     (insert-file-contents f)
                     (count-matches match (point-min) (point-max)))
                   (remove-if 'file-directory-p
                          (directory-files dir t file-match))))))
      (when (called-interactively-p) (message "%d occurrences" count))
      count)))
```

[image]

Comment: Alternatively, you could just use M-x shell-command grep -rh yourword . | wc -w